# Card/USB flash storage: how to trim/discard/reset after heavy usage?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, trim, memory-card

I wonder, if it is possible to 'reset' the controller of an USB drive or a memory card to treat as 'unused' on Linux (Fedora 24)?

Background: I have overwritten an USB drive from /dev/urandom. I.e., I assume that all blocks have been written to, since (as far as I understood) most USB drive and memory card controllers do not keep any spare blocks.
The drive (how to check, if the storage controller supports ATA trim or if the USB controller passes the ATA trim through to the device?)does not support trim - fstrim throws an error and hdparm does not see trim support, i.e.,

```
hdparm -I /dev/sdX | grep -i TRIM
```

Is it generically possible to mark all blocks on thus an USB flash storage as earasable and run a garbage collection on all cells? Or is it, if possible, only limited to certain controllers (USB as well as storage controller)?

#### Follow-Up

Following 
[After an SD card is erased, what value is read from the card? All bits clear or all bits set?](https://superuser.com/questions/568041/after-an-sd-card-is-erased-what-value-is-read-from-the-card-all-bits-clear-or) at least SD-cards should support a *CMD38*, which as a quick format would reset the blocks.

However I have found so far only an official Win/Mac software for sending this command to a device https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/

Presumably (not tried) this also depends on the USB controller to pass-through the command and may only work on SD cards but not necessarily with USB drives?

So far, I have not found a Linux program for easily sending this *CMD38* command to a device.

Comment: “Is it generically possible” – no. In fact, one might even go so far as to say it’s generically *im*possible. I very much doubt that any USB/SD flash controller would be able to do this. They are much less sophisticated than SSD controllers. Unfortunately, I cannot research now.

Comment: yes, I have tried the SD association's formatter under Windows, However, I have not managed to get it access the low-level functions of several SD cards through various USB-readers. Apparently, the USB-controllers in most readers do not pass through the commands/are addressing cards to the PC as other storage types than mmcblk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command you want is [blkdiscard](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/blkdiscard.8.html).  It completely erases an entire partition or block device by means of trimming it.  However, it will only work on SD cards, not USB thumb drives, as I don't think the latter support trim.

Comment: ah, thanks - that is in principle what I am looking for.
Unfortunately, all my card readers (internal as external) are identifying themselves as mass storages of one or the other kind (i.e., thumb drives). I guess with a directly attached card reader, blkdiscard should be my tool for SDs!

Comment: If the underlying device does support trim, then try using the shell script wiper.sh, that comes with hdparm.  For some reason that script (which is scarier because it uses hdparm on lists of blocks) can actually work across USB.

Answer (score 2):

You need [`fstrim`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fstrim.8.html) in the `util-linux` package:

> #NAME
> `fstrim` - discard unused blocks on a mounted filesystem
>
> #SYNOPSIS
> fstrim [-a] [-o offset] [-l length] [-m minimum-size] [-v] mountpoint
>
> #DESCRIPTION
> `fstrim` is used on a mounted filesystem to discard (or "trim") blocks which are not in use by the filesystem.  This is useful for
> solid-state drives (SSDs) and thinly-provisioned storage.
>
> By default, fstrim will discard all unused blocks in the filesystem.  Options may be used to modify this behavior based on
> range or size, as explained below.
>
> The `mountpoint` argument is the pathname of the directory where the filesystem is mounted.
>
> Running  `fstrim` frequently, or even using `mount -o discard`, might negatively affect the lifetime of poor-quality SSD devices.  For
> most desktop and server systems a sufficient trimming frequency is
> once a week.  Note that not all devices support a
> queued trim, so each trim command incurs a performance penalty on whatever else might be trying to use the disk at the time.

This does depend on the ability of the drive or card slot to accept the `TRIM` command, of course.  Cheap USB mass-storage tend not to; newer UAS (USB-attached SCSI) can usually accept `TRIM`.  You can tell whether it's supported using `hdparm -i` - look for "Data Set Management TRIM supported" under the "Commands/features" heading.

Comment: Hi, as mentioned fstrim throws an error (I have added the OS/Fedroa 24) since the device does not support trim, i.e.,  `hdparm -I /dev/sdX | grep -i TRIM`. I would assume, that trim support is controller depenend, i.e., if the storage controller supports ATA trim, the USB controller would have to pass it through as well.

Answer (score 0):

I generally deal with this by using fstrim, unfortunately, on all the usb connected storage devices I ever came across, discard is disabled by default, even on the ones that support it. It is useless mounting the fs with discard option if the disc has it disabled by default: you need to enable it first.
There are however howtos on how to enable it, when supported, and even a limited description on how to make the changes permanent, on a specific device, via udev: however this latter approach I found limiting because I'd want it enabled on any device that supports it.
I achieved this with a udev helper script  called from a generic rule that executes the helper for any scsi disk add or change event.
The udev rule is like this:

```
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="scsi_disk", RUN+="discard $env{DEVPATH}"
```

While the discard helper script is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
logger -t discard "$*"
Dev="$(ls -1 /sys/${1}/device/block)"
logger -t discard "attempting to enable discard on target: ${Dev]}"
 
Lbpu="$(sg_vpd -p lbpv /dev/$Dev | awk '$0 ~ /^ *Unmap command supported/ {print $NF}')"
if [ $Lbpu -eq 1 ]
then
  Mulc=$(sg_vpd -p bl /dev/$Dev | awk '$0 ~ /^ *Maximum unmap LBA count:/ {printf("%i",512 * $NF) }')
  logger -t discard "$Dev Maximum unmap LBA count : $Mulc"
  if  grep -q unmap /sys/$1
  then
    logger -t discard "discard already enabled on $Dev"
  else
    echo unmap > /sys/${1}/provisioning_mode
    echo "$Mulc" > /sys/${1}/device/block/${Dev}/queue/discard_max_bytes
    logger -t discard "discard enabled on $Dev"
  fi
else
  logger -t discard "discard not supported on $Dev"
fi
```

Sorry, using the output of ls in command substitution is somewhat less than optimal and prone to breaking but I was in a hurry to have this functional.

Once discard is active you can remount it with discard option and run fstrim on any mounted fs on devices that support discard.